# Grails extract body data from the request

Tags: java, grails, model-view-controller, httprequest

I have some controller (`ExampleController`) that receives requests with `content-type` `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I need to send all the request data to a different URL using `POST` request. The data needs to be in the same order as received it.

Problem is that the content does not match because `request.getParameterMap()` destroys the order of the data.
In `ExampleController`:

```
def method(){ 
    String s = request.reader.text //this is empty, need a way to read this text
    Map<String, String[]> vars = request.getParameterMap() //it's not good for me   because the map is unordered map 
    //but it full of data

}
```

which does not work.

I need something like:

```
byte[] data = request.getRequestData()
wr.write(data)
```

btw i've tried:

```
InputStream = request.getInputStream()
byte [] bytes = inputStream.getBytes()
```

I've also tried

```
String s = request.reader.text
```

but the string is empty.
I think the main problem is that grails mechanism reads the input stream before the controller even starts and place the data in the parameters hashMap. is there a way to undo it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try using request.reader.text instead.

```
def result = request.reader.text.split('&').inject([:]) { map, token ->
  token.split('=').with { map[it[0]] = it[1] }
  map
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. request.reader.text is an empty String (""). All the data is under request.parameters HashMap

Comment: You have to prevent the request from being parsed first. Supposedly, when using urlMappings you can set parseRequest to false. Then you can read the request body yourself: "/controller/action"(parseRequest:false). However in the latest version of grails, I can't get this to work yet.